# Can't delete repository

Tags: delete

I can neither untick the repository in the picture nor remove it. I tried for at least an hour and it does not get unticked/removed. I have to untick/remove it since I cannot update the system because I get the error:  `E: The repository 'http://www.geogebra.net/linux stable InRelease' is not signed.`

[image]

Comment: Open a terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T) and run `fgrep geogebra /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. What files are listed in purple on the left of the results?

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_www_geogebra_net_linux_-kinetic.list

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_www_geogebra_net_linux_-kinetic.list

Comment: OK, now in that terminal, run `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_www_geogebra_net_linux_-kinetic.list`. It will ask for your password. When you type it in, nothing will show up on your screen, but it will still work.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me. Do you have an idea what the reason behind this was?

Comment: I somehow can't upvote your answer. Sorry.

Comment: The legitimate repository will sign its downloads so that you know that you got it from them and not an impostor and so that you know that the download wasn't corrupted. To check that the signature is correct, Ubuntu needs to be given the repository's public key.

Comment: I see, thank you again.